# Julia - how to define an array of images for FluxML mlp?

Tags: julia

I wish to re-use this code:

https://github.com/FluxML/model-zoo/blob/master/vision/mnist/mlp.jl

but with my own set of images.
I think I need to define an object like imgs of type Array{Array{Gray{Normed{UInt8,8}},2},1}

How do I initialize an array of images to obtain something of the following type:

```
Array{Array{Gray{Normed{UInt8,8}},2},1}
```

I tried this, but it fails:

```
x = Array{Array{ColorTypes.Gray{FixedPointNumbers.Normed{UInt8,8}},2}}(10)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching Array{Array{Gray{Normed{UInt8,8}},2},N} where N(::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  Array{Array{Gray{Normed{UInt8,8}},2},N} where N(::UndefInitializer, ::Int64) where T at boot.jl:416
  Array{Array{Gray{Normed{UInt8,8}},2},N} where N(::UndefInitializer, ::Int64, ::Int64) where T at boot.jl:417
  Array{Array{Gray{Normed{UInt8,8}},2},N} where N(::UndefInitializer, ::Int64, ::Int64, ::Int64) where T at boot.jl:418
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at none:0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create an empty vector use:

```
Array{Array{Gray{Normed{UInt8,8}},2},1}()
```

then you can use the `push!` function to add images to it. Alternatively you could write the same as:

```
Vector{Matrix{Gray{Normed{UInt8,8}}}}()
```

which is a bit easier to read.

Alternatively you can write:

```
Array{Array{Gray{Normed{UInt8,8}},2},1}(undef, 10)
```

To create an uninitialized vector with 10 entries. Then you can use normal index setting syntax to initialize it. Again you could write it also as:

```
Vector{Matrix{Gray{Normed{UInt8,8}}}}(undef, 10)
```